# how to enable google apps chat with normal gmail users

Tags: google, google-workspace, chat

I know that you must change some SV records for it to work but I have no idea which is which because Google just gives a string and GoDaddy has no idea how to input that string into their settings, they just ask for TTL, etc.

Can anybody help? I also cross-posted this to http://nothingtoinstall.com because I have no idea under which category it fits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings for that can be found at http://www.olark.com/gtalk/check_srv

Answer (score 0):

Google talks a lot about the process of federation with third party networks.  It doesn't seem clear whether or not this includes their own network or not.  It does involve updating SRV records though.

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143

http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html#service

Comment: thanks for your effort, I managed to get a reply on nothingtoinstall. settings for godaddy are at http://www.olark.com/gtalk/check_srv

Comment: you should add it as an answer here and accept it as the right one so this question gets marked as solved.